# TYPO3 set template view for controller action

Tags: typo3

I want to use the view template of the list action for my listByYear action. I tried setTemplatePathAndFilename without success. It still cannot find the template.

> Sorry, the requested view was not found.
>
> The technical reason is: No template was found. View could not be
>   resolved for action "listByYear" in class
>   "XXX\YYY\Controller\EventController".

```
/**
  * action listByYear
  * @param \XXX\YYY\Domain\Model\Event $event
  *
  * @return void
  */
  public function listByYearAction(\XXX\YYY\Domain\Model\Event $event)
  {
    $date = $event->getStart();
    $events = $this->eventRepository->findByYear($date->format('Y'));
    $this->view->setTemplatePathAndFilename(
      'typo3conf/ext/' .
      $this->request->getControllerExtensionKey() .
      '/Resources/Private/Templates/Event/List.html'
    );
    debug('typo3conf/ext/' .
    $this->request->getControllerExtensionKey() .
    '/Resources/Private/Templates/Event/List.html');

    $this->view->assign('events', $events);

  }
```

How do I make it use the template for the list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The very short answer is, you can't. The view will already have been initialised and asked to resolve a template well before your action fires, indeed well before any point where you can affect the template filename that it would look for.

The template file that by convention would be resolved *must always exist*. This is what allows your controller action to render. You can then, but I would not recommend that you do, override the template file by setting the template name (the action).

Overall recommendation: use the default template naming logic. If you need to re-use templates, consider refactoring the template parts you need to reuse, placing them in partial templates.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Do not forget the use in the header ..., 
// or write fully qualified class path..
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\View\StandaloneView;


// then add something like this in your action before the assign...
// or maybe create a Standalone view: search the web for "Extbase Standaloneview"
// have a look at: /typo3/sysext/about/Classes/Controller/AboutController.php

$this->view = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(StandaloneView::class);
$this->view->setTemplate('ActionName');
$this->view->setTemplateRootPaths(['EXT:your_ext/Resources/Private/Templates']);
$this->view->setPartialRootPaths(['EXT:your_ext/Resources/Private/Partials']);
$this->view->setLayoutRootPaths(['EXT:your_ext/Resources/Private/Layouts']);

$this->view->assignMultiple([
    'whatever' => $whatever,
    'youLike' => $youLike,
]);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).